# How to prevent zero as value to get recorded in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have some ajax dependent selection boxes which contain provinces, regencies and districts that i used to records user addresses when registering their account.

my view :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control @error('provinces') is-invalid @enderror" name="address_province" id="provinces">
        <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">Pilih Provinsi</option>
        @foreach ($provinces as $province => $value)
            <option value="{{$province}}">{{ $value }}</option>
        @endforeach
        @error('address_province')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
   </select>

   <select class="form-control @error('regencies') is-invalid @enderror" name="address_regency" id="regencies">
      <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">Pilih Kotamadya</option>
      @error('address_regency')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
      </span>
      @enderror
   </select>

   <select class="form-control @error('districts') is-invalid @enderror" name="address_district" id="districts">
       <option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">Pilih Kecamatan/Kabupaten</option>
       @error('address_district')
       <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
           <strong>{{$message}}</strong>
       </span>
       @enderror
   </select>
</div>
```

my controller :

```
public function storeRegister(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'             => 'required|string|max:255',
        'gender'           => 'required|string',
        'birth_place'      => 'required|string',
        'birth_date'       => 'required|date',
        'address_province' => 'required|string',
        'address_regency'  => 'required|string',
        'address_district' => 'required|string',
        'specify_address'  => 'required|string|max:75',
        'email'            => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'phone_number'     => 'required|string|min:9|max:15|unique:users',
    ]);

    $user = new User();

    $user->name = $request->get('name');
    $user->gender = $request->get('gender');
    $user->birth_place = DB::table('provinces')->where('id', $request['birth_place'])->pluck('name');
    $user->birth_date = $request->get('birth_date');
    $user->address_province = DB::table('provinces')->where('id', $request['address_province'])->pluck('name');
    $user->address_regency = DB::table('regencies')->where('id', $request['address_regency'])->pluck('name');
    $user->address_district = DB::table('districts')->where('id', $request['address_district'])->pluck('name');
    $user->specify_address = $request->get('specify_address');
    $user->email = $request->get('email');
    $user->phone_number = $request->get('phone_number');

    $user->save();

    return redirect('/register');
}
```

this is my database when user inputted everything but those selection boxes

[image]

I gave required as filter in my postcontroller but it still recorded, and i realized it wont work coz it will give a default value as 0!

can i do something in my controller so i if i get 0 value it would classified as an error?

Comment: If condition perhaps? Another solution is to remove the 0 from the disabled field and add a required validator to your controller, that way you will get a validation exception which is basically what you're looking for

Comment: ive read all the answers but still have no time to test it out, i guess after done with the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Rule**

```
'address_province'  => ['required', Rule::notIn(['','0'])],
```

Don't forget to use Rule in the controller.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Comment: This is looks very good, even tho i need to use validator to implement something like this, but thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

'address_province' => 'required|regex:^[1-9][0-9]+|not_in:0',

Probable this will help you.